# Does the symmetry of a parabola in finding the maximum area of a rectangle under said parabola matter?

Tags: conic-sections, area

Apologies for my English, I'm a not a native speaker...

---

So I've got this homework, about finding the maximum area of a rectangle under a parabola. I'm using this as a reference to do my work: [How to find the dimensions of a rectangle if its area is to be a maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156623/how-to-find-the-dimensions-of-a-rectangle-if-its-area-is-to-be-a-maximum)

After searching for similar questions, the problems I've found are using parabolas symmetric with respect to the $Y$-axis, thus the rectangle in question can be "split" in half with the same width to the left and to the right of the $Y$-axis, and then we can take $(-x,0)$, $(x,0)$, $(x,y)$ and $(-x,y)$ as the rectangle's points with $(x,y)$ and $(-x,y)$ touching the parabola and $(-x,0)$ and $(x,0)$ touching the x-axis (like my reference above). Could I still do this if the parabola isn't symmetrical with respect to the $Y$-axis? Because then the rectangle wouldn't be "split in half" anymore...

I've tried to do that anyway and I got a good answer.

---

**My work:**

- The parabola's equation is $f(x)=-x^2+4x+3$, from this I determined the rough shape of the parabola
  (by determining the highest point of the graph which is $(2,7)$ and
  the y-intercept which is $y=3$), and placed the rough location of the rectangle inside the parabola

The graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMcsN.png

- The width of the rectangle is $2x$, the  height is $y$. So the area is $2xy$ (I got all these from my reference above, which uses a parabola symmetrical with respect to the $Y$-axis. I'm not sure if I can still use $2xy$ because my parabola isn't symmetrical with respect to the $Y$-axis, hence the question)
- Substituting $f(x)=y$ into $2xy$ I got $A(x)=-2x^3+8x^2+6x$
- $A'(x)=-6x^2+16x+6$ with its roots $3$ and $-(1/3)$
- Substituting $x=3$ into $A(x)$ I got $36$ as the maximum area of my rectangle

Thank you for the kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis of your parabola is at $x=-b/2a=2.$ If you re-write your equation substituting $x=x'+2$ then the new parabola is symmetric with respect to the $Y$ axis. Since the transformation is a horizontal translation, it does not affect considerations about the area of rectangles under the curve.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, where is $x=x'+2$ coming from? And does that mean that the parabola has to be symmetrical with respect to the $Y$ axis for the equation $A(x)=2xy$ to work?

Comment: The substitution $x=x'+2$ is a horizontal shift in the $XY$-plane chosen such that the $Y$ axis becomes the axis of the parabola. And yes, the equation $A(x)=2xy$ supposes symmetry, otherwise it is $A(x)=2(x-2)y$ or more generally $A(x)=2(x+b/2a)y.$

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm more interested on using $A(x)=2(x−2)y$. Is the equation $A(x)=2(x+b/2a)y$ universal i.e. can be used for similar problems with different parabolas? Would you please explain how do you get $A(x)=2(x+b/2a)y$?

Comment: I am shifting $x$ over a distance equal to the $x$-coordinate of the axis of the parabola, which is $-b/2a.$ That holds universally for vertical parabolas.

Comment: Addendum: of course, only those parabolas that hold any rectangles above the $X$-axis at all, i.e., $a<0$ and $b^2-4ac>0$.

Comment: Oh, are you doing it this way?:
Shifting the parabola so that the $Y$ axis becomes the axis of the parabola (i.e. $f(x)=f(x+(-b/2a))$. The shift then of course will give us a new equation of the parabola and then we use this new equation for $y$ in $2xy$

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: Vey well then, thank you so much!

Comment: Wait, I'm really sorry, but I still have a little bit of confusion in me... The equation you posted earlier is $A(x)=2(x−2)y$ instead of just $2xy$ where $y$ is the new equation. Does that mean the $x$ is also affected by the shift and thus changed to $x-x_s$ (where $x_s$ is the shift distance)?

Comment: I am not sure what "affected by" means so I will give a direct recipe. Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a<0$ and $b^2-4ac>0.$ Then the area of the rectangle, bounded by the $X$-axis and the parabola, whose right hand side lies on the line $x=x_0$ is given by $A(x_0)=2(x_0+b/2a)f(x_0).$ If you happen to choose $x_0$ to the left of the axis (like the smaller of the two solutions of $A'(x)=0$) then $A(x_0)$ will actually be the negative of that area.