# Finding area of rectangle under a parabola asymmetrical with respect to the Y-axis: What did I do wrong?

Tags: conic-sections, area

I am using these as references:

1. [How to find the dimensions of a rectangle if its area is to be a maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156623/how-to-find-the-dimensions-of-a-rectangle-if-it)
2. [Does the symmetry of a parabola in finding the maximum area of a rectangle under said parabola matter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575108/does-the-symmetry-of-a-parabola-in-finding-the-maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-under) (related)

---

**Problem:** Find the maximum area of a rectangle inside a parabola whose equation is $f(x)=-x^2+4x+3$

**My Work:**

1. Determining the rough shape of the parabola (by determining the highest point of the graph which is $(2,7)$ and the y-intercept which is $y=3$), and placing the rough location of the rectangle inside the parabola.

[image: graph 1]

2. Shifting the parabola to the left so that the $Y$ axis becomes the axis of the parabola (i.e. $f(x)=f(x+(−b/2a))$). The shift results with a new equation of the parabola, which is $f(x)=-x^2+7$. Graphing it.

[image: graph 2]

3. From [reference 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575108/does-the-symmetry-of-a-parabola-in-finding-the-maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-under), the area's equation is $A(x)=2(x-(-b/2a))(-x^2+7)$ (*I suspect this is where my mistake lies*)  where $-b/2a = 2$, the equation turns out to be a cubic equation $A(x)=-2x^3+4x^2+14x-28$
4. $A'(x)=0$ (to obtain the maximum $A(x)$), with roots $x=-2/3$ and $x=2$
5. Substitute $x=2$ to $A(x)$, $A(2)=-2(8)+4(4)+28-28$ which turns out to be $0$

Thank you for the help...

Comment: Yep, in step 3 you needed to use the original $f(x)$.

Comment: that means we don't need to use $-x^2+7$ at all?

Comment: You should not mix the two parabolas, the original and the shifted one. Either use the original $f(x)$, or alternatively (as user298667 suggests) use the shifted $f(x)$ without subtracting any more axis shift (because the parabola is already symmetric).

Comment: Hmm... So I can choose either $A(x)=2(x-(-b/2a))(-x^2+4x+3)$ **or** $A(x)=2x(-x^2+7)$?

Comment: I have tried both $A(x)$ formulas and I got different results, hmm

Comment: What results did you get? In the first case the maximum is reached at $2+\sqrt\frac73,$ in the second case at $x=\sqrt\frac73.$

Comment: In the second case I too got $x=\sqrt{7/3}$, but for the first case I got $(-6 \pm \sqrt{21})/3$

Comment: It's $-2+\sqrt\frac73,$ sorry about the sign error. And that is equal to your second solution if you take the plus sign in front of the root.

Comment: Hmm, yes, so at least I got the calculations right, thanks. So... By using the first equation (with the original $f(x)$) I got $-2 \pm \sqrt{7/3}$ which is **negative** no matter which sign I took. Does that eliminate this first equation and I should use the second equation (in which the maximum is reached at $x=\sqrt{7/3}$) instead?

Comment: Sorry I take back what I said about the sign error, it *is* +2 but it is easy to make the mistake because the coefficient $a$ is negative.

Comment: Well guess what, I also did the same mistake haha. Yeah I also didn't pay attention to the coefficient $a$. I ended up also getting $2+\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}$. So which equation should I use?

Comment: Both should give $\frac{28}9\sqrt{21}=14.2569\ldots$

Comment: Very well, then. Many thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

After you shift the parabola, you should use new parameters in $f(x)=-x^2+7$. That means $-b/2a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake indeed lies on Step 3, where I either have to:

1. Use the original equation of the parabola (which is $f(x)=-x^2+4x+3$), $A(x)=2(x−(−b/2a))(−x^2+4x+3)$, **or**
2. Use the new equation of the parabola i.e. the equation you got after transforming/shifting the parabola, $A(x)=2x(−x^2+7)$

Both equations derives from the original equation $A(x)=2xy$ (from my [first reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156623/how-to-find-the-dimensions-of-a-rectangle-if-it)).

Instead of doing either steps, I used the new parabola's equation ($−x^2+7$) while still subtracting the axis shift ($(x−(−b/2a))$) despite the fact with my new equation the parabola is already symmetric.

Thanks to [Justpassingby](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/298667/zqd) and [ZQD](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/293332/justpassingby) for the help!