# Evaluate the maximum area of the rectangle touching the parabola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

If I have a rectangle inside a parabola with the equation $y = a - x^2$, such that:

- $a \geq 0$
- Its base lies on the $x$-axis
- Two of its vertices touch the parabola

What is maximum area of the rectangle?

Comment: I have included the extra condition $a \geq 0$ for this problem since the maximum area is finite for that interval.

Here is the [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156623/how-to-find-the-dimensions-of-a-rectangle-if-its-area-is-to-be-a-maximum).

Answer (score 2):

The area of the rectangle is $A=hw$. But $h$ depends on $w$, $w/2$ is the x-distance from the origin ($w$ represents width) so $h=a-(\frac{w}{2})^2 $.

Now we have to maximise $A$ in $$A=w\times (a-\frac{w^2}{4})$$.

Can you do that? Hint: find the roots of the derivative.

Comment: Another hint: The answers are different for $a<1$ and $a>1$.  In a sense, the solution (of a rectangle above the x-axis) does not exist for one of the cases.